# Plotting results onto an actual map with pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Could be a potentially impossible task for my level of python knowledge, but I was thinking if there is a way (perhaps an already existing program) to map the results of a dataframe which comprises of AreaCodes column and Test Results column, onto an actual map of the region.

So my df looks something like this:

```
           PostCode Area   Test Result
0                  BN           P
1                  PE           P
2                  SO         PRS
3                  PE           P
4                  PE           F
5                  CW           P
6                  CW           F
7                   S           P
8                   S           F
9                  SW           P
10                 SW           F
11                 CM           P
12                 CM           F
```

And the PostCode area is for UK. I am potentially looking for something that would resemble a heat map of UK where intensity is controlled by a count of 'P's

Answer (score 0):

You can use cartopy for this.

```
pip install https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/archive/v0.13.1.tar.gz
```

You need geos, shapely und proj4, this is the easiest using anaconda:

```
conda install geos proj4 shapely
```

I downloaded the shape file containing the uk postal areas from here:
http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/

You can then use cartopy to color the areas like this:

```
from cartopy import crs
from cartopy.io import shapereader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

cmap = get_cmap('viridis')

uk_postal_areas = shapereader.Reader('Areas.shp')

ax = plt.axes(projection=crs.Mercator())

values = {
    'BA': 0.5,
    'BN': 0.1,
    'NE': 1.0,
    'IV': 0.7,
    'BT': 0.3,
}

for record in uk_postal_areas.records():
    name = record.attributes['name']
    ax.add_geometries(
            [record.geometry],
            facecolor=cmap(values.get(name, 0)),
            linewidth=0,
            crs=crs.PlateCarree(),
    )

ax.set_extent([-10, 4, 48, 61], crs=crs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, but I keep receiving this error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\eduar\appdata\local\temp\pip-zluvvv-build\ - when installing cartopy